# I want to use my equation to scale a div I can't figure out how to use it as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this for my js and it returns a modified version of the distance between my element and my cursor... I want to use it to scale a separate element, any ideas as to how I would do that?

```
var elm = document.getElementById("qrcode");
elm.addEventListener("mousemove",getcordd , false)

function getcordd(ev){
  var bdns = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var y = ev.clientY - bdns.left;
  var x = ev.clientX - bdns.top;
  var d = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
  var s = (d*0.1)
  console.log (`${s}`);
}
```

This is my CSS

```
.cursor {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    margin: -125px 0 0 -125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    transition: transform 0.8s ease-out;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
        filter: grayscale(2);
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .cursor.is-moving {
    transform: scale (var(`${s}`));
  }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="cursor"></div>

<main>
    
    <h1>Find the QR code for the spotify playlist</h1>
    <div id="qrcode">
        <img id="QRCode" src="img/qr-code.png" alt="">
    </div>
</main>
```

I basically made a custom curser that I would like to scale as I get closer to the element which is a QRCode

The goal would be to make it so the .cursor class scales up to 1 as it gets closer to the #qrcode. And gets smaller as it goes further away. I would like it to be relative to the window...

I am still very new to coding so I am not sure about how to do it and I have not found any information on the internet

Comment: "*I want to use it to scale a separate element,*" - okay, scale what element (can you share your HTML?), in what way? Scale its size, in which direction, one or both?

Comment: Hi, some things I don't understand: your eventlistener is on the qrcode so your cursor will already be on it (ie distance 0 basically) when you look at the mousemove; where do you set the is -moving class; you can't set a CSS variable the way you have it for the scale you;ll need setProperty; why are you subtracting y*y it'll make the distances look a bit odd.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I just added the html and a description

Comment: @AHaworth I am new to codding for web and this was my first attempt... Substracting the y*y was a typo, it would not calculate the distance well indeed! I wanted to use the theorem of Pythagoras... I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you could do it like this

Keep in mind, that `elm.addEventListener("mousemove"...` would trigger function only if your cursor is already moves over `elm` (`#qrcode`), because you attach event listener to `elm`, not to whole `window`.

```
var elm = document.getElementById("qrcode");
var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

elm.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev) {
  var distance = getcordd(ev);
  cursor.style=`transform: scale(${s})`;
}, false);

function getcordd(ev) {
  var bdns = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var y = ev.clientY - bdns.left;
  var x = ev.clientX - bdns.top;
  var d = Math.sqrt(x * x - y * y);
  var s = d * 0.1;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: If I wanted it to be relative to the window how would I do that? I am new to coding sorry